# Reference types inside a C union

Tags: c, enums, typedef, unions

I would like to reference a type inside of a union. I have the following code:

```
typedef union
{
    typedef enum DIGITS_T
    {
        DIGIT_1 = 0,
        DIGIT_2 = 1,
        DIGIT_3 = 2,
        DIGIT_4 = 3

    } DIGITS;

    typedef enum SEGMENTS_T
    {
        SEG_1 = 0,
        SEG_2 = 1,
        SEG_3 = 2,
        SEG_4 = 3,
        SEG_5 = 4,
        SEG_6 = 5,
        SEG_7 = 6,
        SEG_8 = 7

    } SEGMENTS;
} DISPLAY_1;
```

I want to be able to do something like DISPLAY_1.DIGITS or DISPLAY1.SEGMENTS however I am only presented with a list of DIGIT_1, DIGIT_2, DIGIT_3, DIGIT_4, SEG_1, SEG_2, etc when accessing DISPLAY1.

Is it possible to do what I am after or have I not used the union correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't `typedef` inside the `union`...

Comment: Do not post pictures of code.  Paste it into the question.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons when I use the code insert it doesnt grab everything correctly so not everything is formatted or surrounded by the grey box. What would you have me do instead?

Comment: @EugeneSh. So I should just make the enums inside the union then typedef outside the union?

Comment: First define the types. Then use fields of these types in the `union`.

Comment: As for the code - post it as is, we will fix it for you.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneSh. I will try that and keep that in mind. It's hard to know because everyone is so damn picky. You do one thing because someone wants you to but then someone else complains.

Comment: @Schwagmister It should work if you just paste the code into the text section, highlight it, and then press the button with the code brackets.

Comment: It's unclear to me what "do something like DISPLAY_1.DIGITS or DISPLAY1.SEGMENTS" means, but if you are trying to use those character sequences as type names then you are out of luck.  C's member-access operator (`.`) does not provide for qualified names, `typedef` notwithstanding.

Comment: Maybe a bit more explanation would help.  I honestly have no idea what you are trying to do here, nor why unions could help.

Comment: A simple alternative `typedef enum SEG_T {
  SEG_1 = 0, SEG_2, SEG_3
} SEG;  int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", SEG_2);
}`  How does this not meet your goal?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons thanks, that's where I went wrong. I was trying to paste it after clicking the code button.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have two typedefs, digits and segments, and I would like to be able to reference those enumerated types via the union name.

So DISPLAY_1.DIGITS or DISPLAY_1.SEGMENTS

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I guess I'm not sure how I can be any more clear. A union is necessary because I need to group things. So I need to have a DISPLAY_1 union that will group it's digits and segments so I can access them via DISPLAY_1.DIGITS or DISPLAY_1.SEGMENTS

Comment: @chux I need to have digits and segments for different displays. So I need to be able to do DISPLAY_1.DIGITS.DIGIT_1 for instance, or DISPLAY_1.SEGMENTS.SEG_1. That doesnt meet my goal because I cant abstractly use it, I would have to define a seperate typedef enum for each display's digit and segment.

Comment: @Schwagmister ".. have to define a separate typedef enum for each..." is done in your post too, so it is not an additional cost.

Comment: @chux It is when I want to be able to apply a generic typedef to a union. I answered the question so hopefully that will clarify what I was trying to do.

Comment: Please edit your question, an answer is not the right place for that.

Comment: @JensGustedt My original question was answered with the answer, there is just an additional union wrapping the other two, nothing complicated that would require a question edit.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it seems that I wasn't clear enough in my original question for some people, Eugene Sh was able to answer it.

Essentially I have two typedef enum's DIGITS and SEGMENTS. I needed a way to generically apply these to displays DISPLAY_1 and DISPLAY_2, which are unions. So I could access the digits or segments of display 1 or display 2 using DISPLAY_1.DIGITS or DISPLAY_1.SEGMENTS. This works, except I need to be able to use the enumerated type for switch statements.

So what I needed to do was define my enumerated enums outside of the unions, then make a reference to them as an item inside of the union. My code is posted below.

Enumerations:

```
typedef enum DIGITS_T
{
    DIGIT_1 = 0,
    DIGIT_2 = 1,
    DIGIT_3 = 2,
    DIGIT_4 = 3,
    DIGIT_NOTHING = 4

}DIGITS;


typedef enum SEGMENTS_T
{
    SEG_1 = 0,
    SEG_2 = 1,
    SEG_3 = 2,
    SEG_4 = 3,
    SEG_5 = 4,
    SEG_6 = 5,
    SEG_7 = 6,
    SEG_8 = 7,
    SEG_NOTHING = 8

} SEGMENTS;
```

Unions:

```
typedef union
{
    DIGITS Digits;
    SEGMENTS Segments;

} DISPLAY_1;

typedef union
{
    DIGITS Digits;
    SEGMENTS Segments;

} DISPLAY_2;

typedef union
{
    DISPLAY_1 Display_1;
    DISPLAY_2 Display_2;

} DISPLAYS;
```

Example Usage:

```
void Clear_Digit(DISPLAYS display, DIGITS passed_digit)
{
    switch(display)
    {
        case DISPLAYS.Display_1:

            switch(passed_digit)
            {
                case DIGIT_1:

                    break;

                case DIGIT_2:

                    break;

                case DIGIT_3:

                    break;

                case DIGIT_4:

                    break;
            }

            break;

        case DISPLAYS.Display_2:

            switch(passed_digit)
            {
                case DIGIT_1:

                    break;

                case DIGIT_2:

                    break;

                case DIGIT_3:

                    break;

                case DIGIT_4:

                    break;
            }

            break;
    }
}
```